# How can I create a new database in mongodb after dropping it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my end to end tests, I want to drop the "test" database, and then create a new test db. Dropping an entire database is [simple](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/bvdS3B_oNcM):

```
mongoose.connection.db.command( {dropDatabase:1}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

But now how do I now create the test db? I can't find a `createDatabase` or `useDatabase` command in the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/). Do I have to disconnect and reconnnect, or is there a proper command? It would be bizarre if the only way to create a db was as a side effect of connecting to a server.

**update**

I found [some C# code](https://github.com/object/MongOData/blob/master/Mongo.Context.Tests/TestData.cs#L222) that appears to create a database, and it looks like it connects, drops the database, connects again (without disconnecting?) and that creates the new db. This is what I will do for now.

```
    public static MongoDatabase CreateDatabase()
    {
        return GetDatabase(true);
    }

    public static MongoDatabase OpenDatabase()
    {
        return GetDatabase(false);
    }

    private static MongoDatabase GetDatabase(bool clear)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDB"].ConnectionString;
        var databaseName = GetDatabaseName(connectionString);
        var server = new MongoClient(connectionString).GetServer();
        if (clear)
            server.DropDatabase(databaseName);
        return server.GetDatabase(databaseName);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mongodb will create (or recreate) it automatically the next time a document is saved to a collection in that database. You shouldn't need any special code and I think you don't need to reconnect either, just save a document in your tests and you should be good to go. FYI this same pattern applies to mongodb collections - they are implicit create on write.